# No match found in mysql DB with python even though results are in the table

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-workbench

I have code that generates a random number, and a mysql database that has some numbers that should match with many of the randomly generated ones. The program should break once a match is found however it keeps going even though I see several matches generated. I double checked the DB several times and all the numbers are there. I'm brand new to coding so I guess I'm querying the DB wrong? Would appreciate any help. Thank you

```
import random
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    user = "root",
    passwd = "password",
    database = "testdb"
)


my_database = mydb.cursor()
sql_statement = "SELECT * FROM numbers"

my_database.execute(sql_statement)
output = my_database.fetchall()


while True:

    ran = random.randrange(100000,200000,100)

    if ran in output:
        print("MATCH!",ran)
        break
    else:
        print(ran)
'''
```

Comment: `fetchall()` returns a list of tuples.  `ran` is an integer, which does not equal a tuple (even if the tuple contains the integer as its only item).  You need to loop through each tuple.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Do you mean adding 
'for x in output:' at line 16 then indenting the rest?

Comment: Or, if the table only has one column, you could say `if (ran,) in output:`

Comment: That worked! thank you very much!

Comment: Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the mysql python connector documentation, fetchall() returns a list of tuples. So you will need to iterate through each tuple and break when ran is found inside any of the tuples. Alternatively you can use the short-cicuiting function any() as i show below which would be bit more pythonic.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchall.html

```
while True:
    if any(ran in tup for tup in output):
        print("MATCH!", ran)
        break
    else:
        print(ran)
```